# Generic <T extends List<E>> for:each print

Tags: java, for-loop, generics, collections

Sir, please, help to write right syntax. The method has to print all elements of any List extended collection. Following idea of the method:

```
public <T extends List<E>> void printElements(T<E> t){
    for(E elements:e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just take a `List<E>`

Comment: It is not clear what you ask.

Comment: Where is `e` coming from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for `E` or `T`. Printing doesn't require any special knowledge about the items in the list, so you can just accept a generic `List<?>` and pull out `Object`s when iterating over it.

```
public void printElements(List<?> list){
    for (Object item: list) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```